# React-Redux Change state on click

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I don't know how to use Redux properly. I created my state as an object with 10 elements.

Elsewhere in my code I have an input. I thought I would make a function `onChange={somefunction}` that determines if the input is checked.

From here I don’t know what to do. I know I should make an action and reducers, and dispatch the action.

I know that it’s wrong, but here is my code as it is now:

In the action file:

```js
export const cambioCheck = (event) => {
  type: CAMBIOCHECK,
  payload: event.target
};
```

In the reducer file:

```js
export const cambioCheck = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CAMBIOCHECK:
      return { ...state, statoKeys[action.paylod.name] : action.payload.checked };

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Here is where I use this function:

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   statoCheck: (event) => dispatch(cambioCheck(event))
};
```

Comment: Is the input you are checking on the frontend? I'm trying to understand what the goal is. Cause what it sounds like is that you are just trying to determine if an element on the DOM has been clicked on or not.

Comment: What happened when you put your statoCheck on the onClick event? You can set an onClick on your element on the page. Have it go to a method you set and then call your this.props.statoCheck. Hard to tell what the issue is besides looking more into your code.